# Implementing Bemporad optimization algorithm

Tags: combinatorial-optimization

I need to reproduce the results of a relatively old paper of a paper and one of the steps is to solve an IQP problem, the algorithm suggested is [this one](http://cse.lab.imtlucca.it/%7Ebemporad/publications/papers/ecc99-outside1st.pdf). Which I don't know it's the best way to do it since it's quite old (I have understanding of continuous optimization, but when it comes to discrete I know bits and pieces). Also I can't really find a C/C++ implementation of any IQP solver, but this one to me doesn't look particularly difficult to implement.

Section 3.2.  Reports the algorithm which I'll write down here for reference:

1. Take  the  original  MIQP,  relax  all  integrality  constraints,  mark  the  relaxed  QP  with  its  number  of guaranteed switches, i.e.−1. Set $f_{opt}=1$,$k_c=−1$,$x_{opt}=[1;...;1]$ and
   initialize with the relaxed QPthe list of problems to be solved.
2. If the list of problems is empty, terminate and output $f_{opt},x_{opt}$.
3. If there are problems on the list marked by $k_c$, select one  of  them,  remove  it  from  the  list,  and  solve  it.If  the  QP  is  feasible,  denote  its  cost  by $f*$ and  its solution by $x*$.  Go to step 5.  If the QP is infeasible go to 2.
4. If  there  are  no  problems  on  the  list  marked  by $k_c$,increase $k_c$ by 1 and go to 2.
5. *Fathoming by worse cost*: If $f*\geq f_{opt}$,then go to 2
6. *Integer  feasibility* : If $f* < f_{opt}$ and $x*$ satisfies the integrality constraints, then set $f_{opt}=f*$ and $x_{opt}=x*$ .Go to 2
7. *Feasibility but  not  integer  feasibility* Separate  the problem.   Mark  the  sub problems  by  the  number  of guaranteed  switches  in  the fixed  integer  variables. Add  the  subproblems  to  the  list  of  problems.   Goto 3.

It's not 100% clear to me how I form a subproblem to be solved however (I guess this is step 7).
Can you help?

From what I see in figure 2. I think the exploration is exhaustive (with the Outside first strategy). But a subtree isn't explored if it is not feasable.

I think this is the essence of the algorithm, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Professor Bemporad's codes can be downloaded from http://cse.lab.imtlucca.it/~bemporad/hybrid/toolbox/

Comment: It's matlab, I'd need C++. I guess it might be easy enough to convert though. It doesn't change the nature of my question anyway, which is how it works.

Comment: Are all your variables binary?

Comment: Yes, they're. (By the way I just realized that "Outside strategy" is probably what I'm missing, to sure what data structure I would need to achieve that exploration.)

Comment: Links can become broken. Please include the full reference.

Comment: http://or.stackexchange.com may be a better home for this question.

Comment: OK, because all your variables are binary, you can linearize the problem by introducing, for $i<j$, variables $y_{i,j}\ge 0$ to represent $x_i x_j$, together with linear constraints $y_{i,j} \le x_i$, $y_{i,j} \le x_j$, and $y_{i,j} \ge x_i+x_j-1$.  Now use an ILP solver.

Comment: @RobPratt Maybe you can give a full answer or a reference as I don't understand the transformation from non linear to linear (I mean I got a rough idea, but probably more details would be useful as a reference).

Answer (score 1):

Because all your variables are binary, you can linearize the problem by introducing, for $i<j$, variables $y_{i,j} \ge 0$ to represent the product $x_i x_j$, together with linear constraints
\begin{align}
y_{i,j} &\le x_i\\
y_{i,j} &\le x_j\\
y_{i,j} &\ge x_i+x_j−1
\end{align}

A derivation via conjunctive normal form is given [here](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/37/how-to-linearize-the-product-of-two-binary-variables).

Now use an ILP solver.